# Can't use a simple ActiveX. Failed to create 'AxHost'

Tags: activex, atl

I tried to create a simple ATL Object(ActiveX Object) and to use it in C#. I could compile and register it but when I wanted to use it in a C# application I got this error. 
[image]
How can I fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: Getting the exact same crap. If you do work it out let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the process of creating the control, in the ATL Control Wizard, there is a page in the wizard named Interfaces. On this page you need to move the interfaces IPersistStreamInit and IPersistStorage over to Supported.

Only then will the ActiveX control work in a WinForms host.